# Ways to give Domain Users admin rights to turn off Forticlient VPN

Tags: vpn, forticlient

To truly stop Forticlient VPN it requires elevated privileges. Noticing due to it never being truly shut down unless a user does a reboot, that it tends to cause lag when remoting into a desktop. Is there any way to grant users the ability to turn it off without completely compromising security?

Comment: As an administrator you can stop its service without rebooting your machine, as a user without elevated permissions you have less options

Comment: @Ramhound Yeahhh, I need to figure out a way a user without elevated permissions can do it.